# Using exp:query with WHERE = {segment_2} is it safe?

Tags: query-module

I'm querying the database directly using the exp:query tag and filtering results on the value of a segment, is this safe?

How can I make it safe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not. Using segment variables (which is user input, effectively) in a query with the Query module is generally regarded as unsafe.

You should use the [**Active Record**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/activerecord) plugin instead.

Comment: If using INSERT or UPDATE then Active Record methods will escape your data, but will not XSS clean it. Therefore, all data should be run through either `ee()->security->xss_clean()` or `ee()->input->get_post('key', TRUE)` before being stored in the database.


There are some great tips on the ExpressionEngine [Security Guidelines](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/guidelines/security.html) page.


It is also a good idea to escape your values in your query `WHERE='{variable}'`